# How to call method to main method (Program runs but does not print out questions) (Homework)

Tags: java

Response to previous program, Simply placing new balance(); where public static void main is, does not work, and without that the program  runs but nerver prints out the user questions!

```
import java.io.*;

public class cInterest {

    public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException
    {
       //new balance ; 
    }
    public static  double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) throws IOException{

        double amount = 0;

        String input;
        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        System.out.print("How much would you like to take out? ");
        input = myInput.readLine ();
        principal = Double.parseDouble (input);        

        System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
        input = myInput.readLine ();
        rate = Double.parseDouble (input);

        for (int i = 1; i < years; i++) {
            amount = principal * rate * years;
            amount += principal;
        }
        return amount; //- principal;
    }
}
```

Comment: just call it as balance(...);

Comment: Off-topic, you almost certainly want `i` to start at 0. Otherwise if you're trying to run for one year (for instance), you won't even enter the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`balance` is a method, not a class, so you can't use the `new` keyword. You want to *call* the method, instead, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException
{
    double balance = balance(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Awkward hard-coded variables! Ew!
    System.out.println(balance);
}
```

But why are you passing these variables to the method when the user's just going to overwrite them? Your `balance` method should only be responsible for calculating the balance, not gathering user input. You can do that in the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException
{
    // Gather user input.
    String input;
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    System.out.print("How much would you like to take out? ");
    input = myInput.readLine ();
    double principal = Double.parseDouble (input);        

    System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
    input = myInput.readLine ();
    double rate = Double.parseDouble (input);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
    input = myInput.readLine ();
    double years = Double.parseDouble (input);

    // Now do the calculations...
    double balance = balance(principal, rate, years); // Much clearer!
    System.out.println(balance);
}

public static double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) {
    // Calculate the end balance based on the parameters, and return it.
}
```

**Even better** would be to put the gathering of user input into a dedicated method of its own, but I'm far enough off-topic as it is.

Comment: This works, but what do the parameters in the balance do exactly? And the output is always equal to 0

Comment: I've updated the answer with more detail about the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly call the `balance()` method somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`, otherwise, your Stream will not be flushed. You can refer to the [PrintStream javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for more informations.