# Compound Interest formula not working, outputting weird numbers(Does not give me correct answer) in main method and second method

Tags: java, methods

Yes I previously asked questions with the same code, but more problems are arising which i can't seem to fix, to start the compound interest formula is printing out weird numbers of code. Also the line System.out.println(compound); in the main method does not work because of a "Compound cannot be resolved to a variable error) so i can't print it.

```
import java.io.*;

class cexample {
    public static double squared(double x){
        return x*x;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException {
        System.out.println(balance(0.0, 0.0,1.0));
        System.out.println(balance);
    }

    static public double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) throws IOException{
        double amount = 0;
        String input;
        String input2;
        years = 1;
        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.print("How much would you like to take out? ");
        input = myInput.readLine ();
        principal = Double.parseDouble (input);        
        System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
        input2 = myInput.readLine ();
        rate = Double.parseDouble (input2);
        System.out.println("Now, enter the amount of years (1-10)");
        input = myInput.readLine ();
        years = Double.parseDouble (input);  
        for (int i = 0; i < years; i++) {
            // equation, M = P *( 1+ rate) * years^2
            amount = principal * (1 + rate) *( squared(years));
            //amount += principal;
        }
        System.out.println("The amount is " + amount);
        return amount; //- principal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added code, i had some error uploading it, please stop flaming me.

Comment: Care to at least include the link to you previous post or, even better, post the relevant part of your here?  Also, "*weird numbers*" is not really descriptive enough.  To quote a movie: "Help us help you".

Comment: by weird numbers I mean it does not give me the correct answer, and a link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276735/how-to-call-method-to-main-method-program-runs-but-does-not-print-out-questions

Comment: Your formula seems wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Comment: Also, what the heck is `System.out.println(balance);` ? Does it even compile for you? You don't have a variable called `balance`.

Comment: The formula should be right because it is always compounded annualy, i.e the n value which is divided is always 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for compound interest is

```
principal * (1+(rate/compounding periods) ^ (years / compounding periods)
```

In your case compounding periods  is 1

An alternate way of doing the calculation is

```
for(# of years)
  principal *= 1+rate
```

You're doing both and additionally squaring the number of years, though I don't know where you got that idea.

Comment: I guess my source for the formula was incorrect, thanks for the answer

Comment: Can i just write out principal * (1+rate) ^ (years / compounding period) and repalce compounding period with 1 ?

Comment: If the rate is annual, and the compound period is not annual, you should also device the rate by the compound period. See [the formula at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound). Also note that the `^` in Java is not the exponent. Use `Math.pow()` for that.

Comment: Good point, I went too quickly and missed the rate division. As for Math.Pow, I prefer to use pseudocode and not do all the work for him.

Answer (score 0):

The line is giving you problems because `balance` is a method. Go back and reread [my answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276735/how-to-call-method-to-main-method-program-runs-but-does-not-print-out-questions/15276831#15276831). It looks like you just copied parts of the code I gave you without reading or understanding it. You need to make sure you're actually doing what you think you're doing.

And you're always getting 0 as the result (as I already explained in a comment on the previous question) because you're passing in 1 for the year, and your `for` loop starts at 1, so you never actually calculate anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a java expert, but I would use the math function instead, this should do the job:

```
import java.lang.Math;

P * Math.pow((1 + r), (years/period))
```